# Backslashes - Regular Expression - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to build a JS function concatting a list of arguments to a valid path (since I could not be sure whether a part of the path is given with or without slashes)

This is the function:

```
concatPath = function() {
    var path = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)   {
        path += arguments[i].replace("(\\|/)$|^(\\|/)", "") + "/";
    }
    return path;
}
```

The used RegEx matched all beginning and ending slashes and backslashes on http://regexpal.com
But the function does not work properly (RegEx does not match).
Furthermore, Chrome states

**SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/(\)$|^(\)/`: Unterminated group**

when I just use the RegEx

```
 (\\)$|^(\\)
```

However, using the RegEx

```
 (\\)$|^(\\)
```

works fine.

Is it too late or did I missed something special?

Thanks in advance!

Leo

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use a regular expression literal (`/.../`) instead of a string literal (`'...'` or `"..."`) in the call to `replace`.  Strings have their own interpretation of backslashes that kicks in before the regular expression constructor gets a crack at it, so you need an extra level of quoting.

Match one backslash, regular expression literal: `/\\/`

Match one backslash, regular expression in a string: `'\\\\'`

But in a regex literal, you also have to put backslashes in front of the forward slashes, since forward slashes are the delimiter for the whole thing:

```
path += arguments[i].replace(/(\\|\/)$|^(\\|\/)/, "") + "/";
```

Or, if you're married to the use of strings for some reason, this should also work:

```
path += arguments[i].replace("(\\\\|/)$|^(\\\\|/)", "") + "/";
```

As a side note, when your alternatives are single characters, `(x|y)` is overkillish; you can just use a character class (`[xy]`).  In which case you get this:

```
path += arguments[i].replace(/[\\\/]$|^[\\\/]/, "") + "/";

path += arguments[i].replace("[\\\\/]$|^[\\\\/]", "") + "/";
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that did it
can u also tell me why i would have to use '\\\\'? I thought "\\" would be enough since I need one backslash prevent it from escaping the "

Comment: watch out for needing to backslash things in StackOverflow comments, too... :)  When you use the string form, you're going through two parsers - the Javascript parser, which is building the string out of the source code, and the Regexp parser, which is building a regular expression out of the string.  The regexp has to have two backslashes, but in order to get a single backslash in a string from a literal, you have to double it.  Together, that means four backslashes.  Try this: `alert("--> \\\\ <--")` - what you see is what Regexp.new sees when you pass a string to `replace`.

Comment: you're welcome!  you should accept an answer (mine or agent-j's) so that folks will be more likely to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: Using a string lets you drop variables in. #usecase

Answer (score 7):

Try this... it's a little easier to follow with the [character classes].  to match a single `\` with a javascript string you need `\\\\`, which may be what's going on.

`new Regexp('^[\\\\/]|[\\\\/]$')`

You can also try the `/^[\\\/]|[\\\/]$/g` notation.

```
s = 'c:\\folder\\'
console.log(s.replace(/^[\\\/]|[\\\/]$/g, ''))
```