# JavaScript search and RegExp not working for me

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace the value of a string in JavaScript, so I have the following lines of code in a function:

```
result = result.replace('start\introduction', 'index');
console.log(result.search('start\introduction'));
var patt = new RegExp("start\introduction");
console.log(patt.exec(result));
console.log(result)
```

However, the console output is this:

```
-1
null
C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\docs\docs\source\start\introduction.md
```

The string contains the value being searched for, so why are both regexp and search returning not found?

Comment: You need to escape the `\ ` in the search query. `'start\\introduction'`. This is because a backslash starts and escape sequence in a string literal, and the sequence for an actual backslash character is `\\ `

Comment: @squint What would I escape it with?

Comment: I updated my comment above.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769964/backslashes-regular-expression-javascript. Try `console.log(/start\\introduction/.test(result));`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I really see you in all regex questions! hahaha

Comment: @antoni: I will have  a break  soon. George, do those comments above answer your question?

Comment: @squint That's done it!