# Regex for input string start with backslash

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-group

I am comparing String input Start with \\\
For example:

\\\OR-01

Script to match the string

```
 var input = '\\\\\\OR-01'
 var  room = 'OR-01'
 var regex = new RegExp('\\\\\\'+room, 'i');
 var regexResult = regex.exec(input);
 console.log(regexResult);  --output is [ '\\OR-01', index: 2, input: '\\\\\\OR-01' ]
```

But if I change the input Which starts with \W, \B, \N my logic is not working.

```
 var input = '\\\\\\WR-01'
 var  room = 'WR-01'
 var regex =  new RegExp('\\\\\\'+room, 'i');
 var regexResult = regex.exec(input);
 console.log(regexResult); ------output is null.
```

For \W, \B, \N may be other characters as well I am getting null. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Backslashes in JS regex is a known problem: to match one, use `'\\\\'` in a regex constructor notation. If you have 3, use 4 x 3 = 12 backslashes.

Comment: It's working, but why do we need to put 1:4 Backslashes, could you please explain the reason.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769964/backslashes-regular-expression-javascript