# Jest configuration, help me decipher this file pattern: [/\\\\]

Tags: node.js, regex, jestjs

I was digging around in the example projects in the Next.js project and in the Jest configuration for the Typescript project I found this pattern in the testPathIgnorePatterns in the Jest configuration:

```
<rootDir>[/\\\\](node_modules|.next)[/\\\\]
```

What exactly is this? Looks somewhat like a regular expression, but I don't understand the `[/\\\\]` part?

I would like to extend the expression above with a positive lookahead in order to exclude certain node modules from being ignored, but I'm not quite sure how to achieve this?

Comment: It matches a slash or a backslash, i.e. path separators on Windows or not; the backlashes have to be escaped twice for JSON string and regex syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769964/backslashes-regular-expression-javascript is related question but not a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

This is regular expression, where `\\\\` means a single `\`, so `[/\\\\]` character class means either `/` slash or `\` backslash character.

The context for it is that it's provided as a string in Jest JSON configuration:

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": "<rootDir>[/\\\\](node_modules|.next)[/\\\\]"
```

The string is supposed to be passed to `new RegExp` constructor then, with `<rootDir>` placeholder being replaced by actual path. By being used this way, `\` character needs to be escaped twice - once as JavaScript string:

```
"\\"; // a backslash
"\"; // syntax error
```

And another time as regular expression:

```
/^[\\]$/.test("\\") // true
/^[\]$/.test("\\") // syntax error
```